# Could a moderator please close this question? Now?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[How important is a LinkedIn profile?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11267/437)

This question is entirely opinion-based. Thanks.

Comment: If you think it's a problem, flagging it is the best way to call it to the moderators' attention.

Comment: @keshlam keep in mind as moderators we nearly _never_ close things as a result of flags (except spam or other stuff like that). The site is community moderated for a reason and all of us are hesitant to cast close votes unless there are already quite a few community votes on a question to begin with.

Comment: Granted, but if someone seriously believes downvotes are insufficient flags are a logical next step designed into the system. Of course if you want to argue your case Meta is the right place to do it, but unless you have a novel argument that isn't likely to do anything the others wouldn't... except possibly help you understand why you're wrong.

Comment: Why on earth are you asking for a moderator?

Answer (score 12):

The question is over 3 years old. Your concept of urgency seems a little off.

Even if there was a critical issue that needed to be resolved quickly, this isn't the way to do it. You have plenty of other options:

- You have close votes to start the closing process.
- You can comment why the question should be closed or how it should be improved to avoid closing.
- You can link it on chat if you want to solicit input on the question from other users.
- You can flag it for moderator attention. If mods need to act quickly, this is the fastest way of bringing something to their attention.

The voting process is designed to ensure that the community as a whole determines whether a question fits this site and your personal opinion only counts for one of those votes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing what is so bad about this question that it needs anything more than the regular close vote. It's not actively causing harm to the site, so let's just let the normal process take effect.

Comment: OK. Could you please apply the "regular" close vote then? Thank you.

Comment: It's outvoted, I assume. Let it go.

Answer (score 2):

**That looks like a good question to me.**

The question of which subjective questions are inappropriate is itself subjective.  However, I see nothing that contravenes [the site guidelines for bad questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your
>   answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
>   answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no
>   actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I
>   do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if
>   ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Furthermore, the question has inspired good, useful answers.  Hopefully it won't get closed.